# Connecting to COM serial port through USB with Putty

Tags: usb

I am trying to use my android phone connected to my PC as an SMS gateway by executing AT commands.

I have attached the phone to the PC (Windows 7), and device manager shows that it is in COM4 port. I opened PUTTY in administrator mode and tried connecting to COM4 but it just shows a black screen with the green cursor but won't let me type anything.

I tried playing around with the values of "Local Echo" and "Local Line Editing" as I found in one of the suggestions in another question here, but the best I can get (set both to "Force On"), I can type stuff on Putty but it doesn't really do anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly have you connected your phone to your PC? Most phones don't have a user-accessible serial port.

Comment: @DanHulme I am using a regular USB connection. From what I've read online, this would create a virtual com port connection which it did as I checked from device manager. I'm trying out with putty if I can send messages using AT commands as I'm planning to build an application that will send SMS using the android phone as an SMS gateway.

Comment: You can't use the USB connection like a serial connection to a modem. That's just not how it works. You can probably find an app that acts as a server through Wi-Fi to send SMS messages, but I don't think you'll find anything that accepts AT commands.

Comment: @DanHulme I thought I read somewhere that can be done. I think the app is a better approach. Will this app be something like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that on phones or 3g devices that are recognized as modems by the os.

I had one Nokia communicator that I used for that and controlled this using at commands.
 Also I had a Sony laptop with a 3g card that could be controlled with at commands and inclusive enable the hidden gps :)

That Sony still sends his coordinates to my Web server so I know where he has been :) if stolen :)

You need to check if your hardware is compatible and the OS has the correct driver implementation.